# フレームワークが巨大なためアプリのサイズが大きくなってしまう

Tags: swift, ios

Swift3で、バナー広告表示のためにAdMobを使用しています。AdMobを使用するためにGoogleMobileAds.frameworkをアプリに組み込みました。このフレームワークが30MB〜40MB近くあり、アプリをコンパイルすると全体で50MB近くなってしまいます。そこで、アプリのサイズを軽量化したいのですが、バナー広告で使う機能だけを絞ってフレームワークを利用することはできないでしょうか。コードは下記のように実装しています。

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class ViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate {

    private var bannerView: GADBannerView = GADBannerView() // 広告バナー

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // AdMob広告設定
    bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)
    bannerView.adUnitID = ""  // AdMobで発行された広告ユニットIDを設定
    bannerView.delegate = self
    bannerView.rootViewController = self
    let gadRequest:GADRequest = GADRequest()
    gadRequest.testDevices = [""] // テスト用の広告を表示する時のみ使用（申請時に削除）
    bannerView.load(gadRequest)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

単純にビルドして生成されるパッケージのサイズは最終的なアプリのサイズではありません。その中には各デバイスに配信される際には実際に使われないアーキテクチャのバイナリやビットコードなど、使われないかもしれないすべてのものが含まれているため実際よりかなり大きくなっています。

アップルが公開しているドキュメントを参考にして、配信される際の実際のサイズにおおよそ近いサイズを求めてみてください。おそらく数Mバイトから十数Mバイト程度になるのではないでしょうか？

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1795/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014195-CH1-GET_SIZE_REPORT

上記のドキュメントの **Getting an App Size Report** セクションです。

> 1. Archive your app.
> 2. Export your archive for testing outside the store.
> 3. Select “Export for specific devices” and choose “All compatible device variants” from the pop-up menu.
> 4. Select "Rebuild from bitcode."

アプリをアーカイブし、アーカイブに対してXcodeからAppStore以外での配布の設定で“Export for specific devices”と“All compatible device variants”を選択してエクスポート、"Rebuild from bitcode."を有効にするのを忘れないでください。

そうすると`App Thinning Size Report.txt`というファイルが同時に出力されますので、そこに配信される際のおおよそのサイズが記録されています。

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 8.3 でアプリサイズが巨大になるバグが報告されていますが、 8.3.1 で修正されているのでもし 8.3 をお使いの場合はアップデートで直るかもしれません

> Fixed an issue that could produce app archives that were larger than necessary. Support for app archives built in Xcode 8.3 will be deprecated. (31302382)

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。Xcodeのバージョンを確認したところ、8.3.2でした。しかしながら、アプリの容量は大きいままです。GoogleMobileAds.frameworkではなく他のところで容量を無駄に大きくしているような気もします。どのソースが、あるいはフレームワークが容量を大きくしているのかを調べる方法をご存知でしたら教えて頂けると助かります。