# アプリの容量が異常に大きい

Tags: swift, ios

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

アプリ開発の実機テストをしてみたところ画像のように
"書類とデータ"と"appのサイズ"に大きく差が出ます。
それほど凝ったアプリではないと思うのですが、こんなに"appのサイズ"が大きくなってしまう原因が分かりません。どのようにしたら改善できるかお願いします。

フレームワークはfirebaseとadmobのみ入れてます。

Answer (score 1):

XcodeのRunボタンで単純にインストールした場合、そこに表示される容量はそれくらいで妥当だと思います。何も追加しない初期テンプレートのままの状態のプロジェクトをXcodeから転送した場合もそれくらいの容量になりました（私の環境では39MB）。

アプリの容量についてはデバッグビルドとAppStoreにアップロードするバイナリ、実際に配信されたバイナリなどでそれぞれ異なります。

実際に配信された場合のアプリの容量を調べる方法がありますので、詳しくは下記の別の回答を参照して調べてみてください。実際にはもっと小さくなることがわかると思います。

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/35086/5519

私の環境で初期状態のテンプレートにFirebaseとAdMobを追加してビルドしたアプリを上記の手順でエクスポートした場合のサイズは、未圧縮で10.2 MB、圧縮後で3.4 MBとなり、そのIPAファイルをデバイスにインストールすると、iPhoneストレージの画面に表示される数値は10.2 MBでした。
このことと、初期状態でも同じことを確認したので、FirebaseとAdMobを使うことによる容量の増加は3MBほどで、アプリ全体のサイズは少なくとも10MBほどになると思われます。

```
Supported devices: Universal
App + On Demand Resources size: 3.4 MB compressed, 10.2 MB uncompressed
App size: 3.4 MB compressed, 10.2 MB uncompressed
On Demand Resources size: Zero KB compressed, Zero KB uncompressed
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！フレームワークの削除などして、色々手詰まりでしたの解決しそうで良かったです。